# Synchronizing state in custom hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, synchronization, react-hooks, state

**TL/DR:**
How can I properly synchronize states between two hooks?

> **Implementation detail:**
>
> I'm gonna simplify the example and use `useState`, instead of using the first custom hook I'm actually using in order to simplify the question.
>
> Essentially what the omitted hook does is it returns a `state` and helper functions. So just to paint the picture:
>
> ```
> const [email, onEmailChange, onEmailBlur] = useField('init', isEmailValid)
> ```
>
> replaced in question by simply *(although it's technically redundant here)*
>
> ```
>  const [email, setEmail] = useState('hi')
> ```
>
> *The reason why I'm leaving this excerpt here is so I don't get comments/answers that the initial `useState` is redundant*

**What works**:
Passing a state reference to a basic function that simply returns it.

```
const useForm = (...fields) => {
  return {
    fields,
  }
}
const form = useForm(email) // updates correctly
```

**Where the issue starts**:
Now obviously this thing wouldn't even require a hook. Issue arises, when I try to add bit more complex logic

```
const useForm = (submitFunction, ...fields) => {
  const initialForm = {
    fields,
    wasSubmitted: false,
  }
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialForm)

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (!fields.some(({ error }) => !!error) {
       submitFunction()
    }
    setForm({
      fields,
      wasSubmitted: true,
    })
  }

  return [form, handleSubmit] // now the state no longer updates
}
```

> Now I do have a suspicion as to why this is happening. Simply because `useState` initializes a new instance of the state, so we are simply returning the initalized values from the passed states.

Issue is, I can't really wrap my head around as to how I would be able to synchronize these.

**Editable example with both working and non-working hook**:

[image: Edit vibrant-darwin-8s1cv]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned it's because the `useState` in `useForm` is setting the initial value of `form` state and its value does not change in next renders.

If you want to keep `form` and `fields` synchronized, you can use a `useEffect` to update the value of `form` every time a value in `fields` changes.

```js
...
const [form, setForm] = useState<Form>(initialForm);

useEffect(() => {
  setForm(formState => ({ ...formState, fields }))
}, fields);
...
```

The issue with this solution is that the `setForm` in the `useEffect` causes another rerender every time a value in `fields` changes.

Another way to fix this issue is to not save `fields` value in the state and only keep `wasSubmitted` in the state of the `useForm`.

```js
const useForm = (submitFunction, ...fields) => {
  const [wasSubmitted, setWasSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (fields.some(field => field === "run")) {
      submitFunction();
    }
    setWasSubmitted(true);
  };

  return [{ fields, wasSubmitted }, handleSubmit];
};
```

Comment: Hmmm technically I feel like that's more of circumventing the issue rather than solving it, but I cannot disagree with it's practicality. 

I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if anyone else comes up with anything that tackles the issue directly, but yeah this does kinda do the trick.

Comment: You're tight. I added a section to solve the problem without changing it. I hope it helps.